# Authoritative Reference for Astronomical Constants

Tags: resource-recommendations, astronomy, data

Is there a reference that is considered authoritative when it comes to astronomical data, especially for the planets and their satellites and the Sun?

I've been using the most recent CRC *Handbook of Chemistry and Physics* and Lang's *Astrophysical Data: Planets and Stars* (the latter being somewhat old, published in 1992). Even accounting for the age difference in the publications, there are some unsettling disparities.

Therefore, I'd like to have a "go to" source for astronomical data and would welcome any pointers.

Comment: Is there any particular/specific data you are looking for as "astronomical data" is rather vague (though I guess when identifying planets & moons, you are looking for masses, radii, orbital periods, etc?)

Comment: Googling Solar System Constants gave a number of hits. This one from JPL looks good - [Planetary Physical Parameters](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/planets/phys_par.html)

Comment: @KyleKanos Yes, I'm looking for masses, radii, orbital periods, and other data relevant to orbital mechanics (especially of the bodies in the Milky Way galaxy). It seems like these data would be among the most basic of the figures included in more expansive sources.

Comment: @mmesser314 thank you for your input, though Google is not exactly the kind of authoritative resource I'm looking for. JPL is, of course, reputable, but I'm not sure about authoritative. To be clear, by authoritative, I mean a source I can unimpeachably cite, much like the PDG's *The Review of Particle Physics* for that discipline. Incidentally, it occurred to me to try Google before asking this question.

Comment: No criticism implied. Sometimes people need a suggested topic for a fruitful Google. You might try space agencies like ESU or NASA because they need good data to plan trajectories of spacecraft. JPL does publish lots of this kind of data. E.G. see https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/sb/sats.html